# Force Microsoft Teams to use OS-native Notifications

Tags: windows, macos, notifications, microsoft-teams

Using Microsoft Teams, I get ugly purple no-padding notifications on my Desktop:

[image: Microsoft Teams Notification]

In addition to being non-standard, these alerts [do not respect](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/37032007-teams-does-not-respect-do-not-disturb-on-macos) my system's Do Not Disturb settings.

How can I force Microsoft Teams to use the operating system's default notifications UI instead?

- macOS Notification Center
- Windows 10 Notifications

Answer (score 11):

There seems to be a development option `enableNativeNotification` that will enable system notifications in Microsoft teams. I unfortunately cannot try this myself, as the development preview needed to enable the option is not enabled for my organization.

---

Information taken from [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftTeams/comments/fo4xg8/native_os_teams_notifications/flgwrak/) which provided [these screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy3fu.jpg).

> FWIW for anyone frustrated at the custom notifications, you can enable Native Notifications by throwing Teams into developer mode and then left clicking the Teams tray icon 7 times. Right clicking will then give you tons of options, including Hooks. From here, you can enable Native Notifications (defaults to false, so turn it to true) and voila, native notifications.

---

The steps seem to be:

1. Enable the [Public Developer Preview for Microsoft Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro)

   - Note: *Developer preview is enabled on a per-client basis, but the option to turn on developer preview is controlled at the organization level.*

     - See the [Answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1638418/122042) for a possible workaround if your org restricts access.
2. Tap on your app icon **7 times** to [enable the dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678907/how-can-i-open-the-dev-tools-in-the-microsoft-teams-desktop-client):

   - Windows: System Tray icon
   - macOS: Dock icon
3. Access the Developer Preview tools:

   - Windows: Right-click the System Tray icon. Select `Open DevTools`.
   - macOS: select "Development" from the app's main menu bar. You can also edit the settings directly at `~/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/Teams/settings.json`
4. Set the following options to `true`: `enableNativeNotification`, `enableMacNativeNotification`
5. Restart Microsoft Teams

---

If all goes well, Teams should then use the system's native notification system:

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI on macOS, after you've enabled enableMacNativeNotification and enableNativeNotification, you still might have to go in the Teams settings, and switch it to Mac.

Comment: Confirmed this is working on macOS Big Sur. A couple of things that got me: 1) it wasn't clear that these settings are under the "Hooks" submenu under the Development menu, and 2) setting `enableMacNativeNotification` via the menu did not work for me - I still had to open settings.json and set it there - then I was able to restart, and go into settings and set notification style to Mac, after which I was prompted by the OS to allow teams notifications.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. There's no settings whatsoever accessible via the development menu, and changes to the settings.json are reset after restarting Teams. Have to wait I guess...

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich see the other answer about forcing the dev menu to appear even if your organization restricts access.

Comment: @pkamb aha! We did not have preview features enabled in our Teams admin policy. [This Microsoft page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/public-preview-doc-updates) provides steps for org admins to do so - might help others with domain admin privileges.

Comment: @CoryW. I was also able to adopt the settings.json. But after that I did not find the option to set notifications in the teams setting. Do you have a screenshot or something else where I can see how to configure that?

Comment: @ryder I actually don't see the option in my Teams app anymore either, it seems the Developer menu is much different now that it was before. I'm not sure where to set it now. Sorry!

Answer (score 6):

OS-Native Teams Notifications can be enabled even if your organization disabled beta access, by modifying the settings request with a proxy software such as Charles or Proxyman.

I found the following instructions [on the macOS UserVoice ticket](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16941685-use-built-in-notifications-for-macos) mentioned above:

Instructions:

1. Install and open Proxyman
2. Select "certificate > install certificate on this mac" from the menu and follow the steps
3. enable https response for teams.microsoft.com
4. option-click on teams.microsoft.com > tools > scripting
5. create new script for `https://teams.microsoft.com/package/desktopclient/settings/osx` with the following `onResponse` function:

```
function onResponse(context, url, request, response) {
    
    // Update Body
    var body = response.body;
    body["settings"]["enableNativeNotification"] = true;
    body["settings"]["enableMacNativeNotification"] = true;
    response.body = body;
    
    // Done
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Clever! Worked just fine for me! Thanks

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you.

Comment: Pure Genius :) Thanks

Comment: Take note it appears that the URL has changed to `https://teams.microsoft.com/desktopclient/settings/osx`

Answer (score 3):

The Teams development team is testing and adding Native Notifications for Windows, macOS, and Linux. The tickets, **created in 2016**, have been updated in December 2020 indicating that the feature will be released in early 2021.

These requests are tracked on the Microsoft Teams User Feedback Forum:

- [Integrate with MacOS notifications](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16941685-use-built-in-notifications-for-macos) (November 2016)

  - ⚠️ on 2021 roadmap
- [Integrate with Windows 10 notification center](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16950997-integrate-with-windows-10-notification-center) (November 2016)

  - ✅ [Implemented for Windows April 2021](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-notifications-style-in-teams-0da93820-93d0-4da3-86b6-fc28d19908e3)
- [Introduce Freedesktop dbus notifications for Linux](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/39279040-introduce-freedesktop-dbus-notifications-for-linux) (December 2019)

  - ✅ Implemented for Linux December 2020

Comment: Define "early", haha